# How can I properly identify only modified and new files between the source code of a project in different environments?

Tags: git

I try to mix the source code of a project hosted in production with a local copy of the same project with a few modifications. (Modifications and new files may have been made to the production copy) The local copy has a git repository I have tried through it to be able to identify the modified and new files in either of the two environments, then correct these incidents and once resolved, upload an updated copy of the project to production

The way I try the above is as follows

1. In the local repository I have created a new branch named test/migration
2. In this branch I pasted all the source code taken from the copy of the project in production

At this point the problem I find is that when copying the production code local, when using git status, all the files are marked as modified independently that when they are reviewed they have the exact content

This makes it difficult for me to identify the relevant files, as there are more than 6000 files

I appreciate your advice

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you did exactly. What you want to do is compare `master` in your local git repo with the current state in production, is that correct? In that case, check out `master`, then copy the files from production over your sandbox, and I think that should give you the diff you want.

Comment: Alternatively, commit everything into your `test/migration` branch and do `git diff master test/migration`. In any case, if you point `git diff` to a tree-ish for each of the two states you want to compare, it should tell you what you want to see. Add `--stat` option to `git diff` to just see the list of files changes.

Comment: thanks for answering Joanis. The context that I think is missing is that the copy of the project on my personal computer is a git repository while the copy in production does not have any repository, it is just a set of files that I drop in a branch in my local with I intend to overwrite my local files and mark those that are different when doing git status as modified. At least I hope so. I hope I have explained myself correctly,

Comment: @Mario : when comparing two files that "have the exact [same] content", check for changes on "hidden" characters : line endings, BOM, absence/presence of an empty line at end of ile ...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** I think you're just missing a call to `git reset` to tell git to consider the local file state against the current `HEAD`.

#### The setup

I'm going to assume the following setup, based on your description

- `RemoteURL` is your Git repo for cloning
- `ProdCopy` is a directory where you copied the contents from prod.

#### Solution: create and tidy a sandbox for ProdCopy

start by cloning `RemoteURL` into a new, empty sandbox, and put the `ProdCopy` files into it:

```
git clone --no-checkout RemoteURL ProdSandbox
```

Now, you have a sandbox with only a `.git` folder in it. Copy all the files from `ProdCopy` into it:

```
cp -ar ProdCopy/* ProdSandbox
```

Now, `git status` tells you everything has changed, which makes me think I just reproduced exactly what you said in the question that you did. Let's tell git to consider what's in the sandbox as your current state:

```
git reset
```

Now, `git status` and `git diff` will only report what is actually different between the files in `ProdSandbox` and `origin/main` (or whatever `origin/HEAD` points to).

If you want to compare to a different commit or branch, add that to the `git reset`, but in that case you probably want to create your `test/migration` branch first, because this command will move you current branch's pointer:

```
git checkout -b test/migration
git reset <some branch or commit>
```

To commit the changes you want, create your `test/migration` if you haven't already, and commit as usual.